# Matrices of functions commute

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

Given two $n\times n$ matrices  $A(z), B(z)$ with entire functions entries; with

$A$ and $B$  invertible on $\mathbb{C}$, and $A$ is normal (i.e., $A(z)A^{*}(z)=A^{*}(z)A(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$).

If $A(z)B(z)=B(z)A(z)$ , **and** $A(z)B^{*}(z)=B^{*}(z)A(z)$  for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$,

does this imply that

$$A(z)B(w)=B(w)A(z) , \quad \text{for all}\; z,w\in \mathbb{C}?$$

***Added:*** May be showing if $A(z)A(w)=A(w)A(z)$ could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$A(z)=B(z)= \begin{bmatrix} z & z-1 \\ z+1 & z \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $A$ is invertible and normal for all $z$. However, $A(1)B(2)\neq B(2)A(1)$.